# Self Hosted Meteor App Fibers Issue

Tags: node.js, meteor, fibers

Good Morning

I've have this issue for the last few days and I'm really frustrated with the lack of support/documentation. My error is below:

/usr/share/nginx/html/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.Npm.require (/usr/share/nginx/html/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:142:18)
    at packages/npm-node-aes-gcm/wrapper.js:2:1
    at /usr/share/nginx/html/bundle/programs/server/packages/npm-node-aes-gcm.js:33:4
    at /usr/share/nginx/html/bundle/programs/server/packages/npm-node-aes-gcm.js:42:3
    at /usr/share/nginx/html/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1

fibers -v 1.0.5
node -v 0.12.4
meteor -v 1.1.0.2

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Meteor supports version **v0.10.36+** of node only. v0.11.x and v0.12.x are not supported. You are using **0.12.4**.

You will have to downgrade your version of node or manage it using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to run your app.

There's an open ticket about this on github: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3666

---

For those who want more actionable steps:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash # install nvm
nvm install 0.10.36
nvm use 0.10.36
node main.js
```

Comment: @Akshat, Thank You. I did't knew about nvm. It saved me a lot of time!